# C# NetSuite WebServices: Get value from custom field in saved search (ItemSearchAdvanced)

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I'm using C# MVC to connect to NetSuite using their WebServices API.  I have some current code that calls a saved search of inventory items.  Here is the current code that is working perfectly:

```
ItemSearchAdvanced searchItems = new ItemSearchAdvanced();
searchItems.savedSearchId = "128";
SearchResult result = netSuiteSvc.search(searchItems);
int totalRecords = 0;
int processedRecords = 0;

UpdateNetsuitePriceListModel returnObj = new UpdateNetsuitePriceListModel();
returnObj.NewPriceList = new List<NetSuitePriceListRecord>();
if (result.status.isSuccess)
{
    SearchRow[] searchRows = result.searchRowList;
    if (searchRows != null && searchRows.Length >= 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < searchRows.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            ItemSearchRow itemRow = (ItemSearchRow)searchRows[i];
            if (itemRow.basic.itemId != null && itemRow.basic.mpn != null && itemRow.basic.basePrice != null && itemRow.basic.salesDescription != null)
            {
                returnObj.NewPriceList.Add(new NetSuitePriceListRecord()
                {
                    ItemId = itemRow.basic.itemId[0].searchValue,
                    ManufacturerPartNumber = itemRow.basic.mpn[0].searchValue,
                    ContractPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(itemRow.basic.basePrice[0].searchValue),
                    Cost = CalculateProductCostForIngram(Convert.ToDecimal(itemRow.basic.basePrice[0].searchValue)),
                    Description = itemRow.basic.salesDescription[0].searchValue
                });
                processedRecords++;
            }
            totalRecords++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("NetSuite Part List Blank");
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("NetSuite Part List Search Failure");
}
```

Now I have need to pull the itemId from a custom added field rather than the default itemId field.

Obviously since this is a custom field it isn't a property of ItemSearchRowBasic.  It looks like instead of the property I can choose "customFieldList" which is an array of "SearchColumnCustomField".  If I choose an index for the array I can see that SearchColumnCustomField contains:

- customLabel
- internalId
- scriptId

I imagine I should be able to get the internalId of the SearchColumnCustomField and somehow use that to get the search value for that custom column but I've had some trouble finding any examples that fit so far.

This custom field is a free form text field added to all inventory items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting scriptId with the ID of the field ("custitem_xyz"). That should work.

Before 2013 one would use internalId, but since then it changed to scriptId.

Comment: Are you saying to loop through the array of SearchColumnCustomField objects and get the one that has a scriptid that mathces the field ID of the column I'm looking to get the value from?  If so how do I then get the value from that object, I only see customLabel, internalId and scriptId as properties to get from the object.  Sorry if I misunderstood your proposed solution.  Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. Depending on the field type (List/Record, Free Form text, Number, etc.), the custom field returned in the result will be of a specialized type, for example SearchColumnSelectCustomField, SearchColumnStringCustomField, SearchColumnLongCustomField, etc. You can check the type of the field returned, cast it to the appropriate specialized type, and on this one you'll have access to the getSearchValue() method, which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: You might want to validate that your field is returned, by looking at the SOAP response directly. It can be found in NetSuite, under Setup -> Integration -> Web Service Usage Logs. In there you'll be able to analyse the full response returned, and act on it accordingly.

Comment: Casting to the specific type of search column select custom field to expose the searchValue property is exactly what I was looking for.  Just tested and it works great.  Also you're right that the scriptId matches custom field ID.  The Web Service Usage Logs are also super useful and I didn't even know they existed before.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to loop over the CustomRecord items in the customFieldList.  I then usually check for a specific type so I can cast to the correct object, but with some reflection you could probably avoid that.

```
foreach (Record r in mySearchResponse.recordList){
  foreach (CustomFieldRef cr in ((CustomRecord)r).customFieldList){
    if (cr.GetType().Name == "SelectCustomFieldRef"){
      if (((SelectCustomFieldRef)cr).scriptId == "my_custom_field"){
        internalID = ((CustomRecord)r).internalId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the future I'll test out using reflection to see if I can get the "correct" type, however worst case you're right that I could loop through and test casting to different types until I expose the SearchValue I'm looking for.  Thanks.