# NetSuite Web Services Custom Field in Searches

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I cant seem to pull the custom field values of a transaction search using Web Services.

```
        searchTransaction.savedSearchId = "2017";
        SearchResult result = netsuite.search(searchTransaction);

        if(result.status.isSuccess)
        {
            SearchRow[] searchRows = result.searchRowList;
            if(searchRows != null && searchRows.Length >= 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchRows.Length; i++)
                {
                    TransactionSearchRow transactionRow = (TransactionSearchRow)searchRows[i];
                    var iid = transactionRow.basic.internalId[0].searchValue;
                    double amount = transactionRow.basic.amount[0].searchValue;
                    string custfild = transactionRow.basic.customFieldList[0].scriptId;

                    Console.WriteLine("\n Transaction ID: " + iid.internalId);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Amount: " + amount.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("\n customfield: " + custfield.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that the field is being returned because I can see it in the xml response.  And custfield.ToString() does return the internal ID of the custom field.

I just cant seem to get the actual value.

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467766/c-sharp-netsuite-webservices-get-value-from-custom-field-in-saved-search-items), was the same they said "Casting to the specific type of search column select custom field to expose the searchValue property". I cant figure out exactly what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, posting in case anyone else has the same question:

```
        searchTransaction.savedSearchId = "2017";
        SearchResult result = netsuite.search(searchTransaction);

        if(result.status.isSuccess)
        {
            SearchRow[] searchRows = result.searchRowList;
            if(searchRows != null && searchRows.Length >= 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchRows.Length; i++)
                {
                    TransactionSearchRow transactionRow = (TransactionSearchRow)searchRows[i];
                    var iid = transactionRow.basic.internalId[0].searchValue;
                    double amount = transactionRow.basic.amount[0].searchValue;
                    string custfild = transactionRow.basic.customFieldList[0].scriptId;

                    SearchColumnStringCustomField custfild =  (SearchColumnStringCustomField)transactionRow.basic.customFieldList[0];

                    Console.WriteLine("\n Transaction ID: " + iid.internalId);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Amount: " + amount.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("\n custfild: " + custfild.searchValue);

                }
            }
        }
```